# How do i reference complex json objects in my model so they can be displayed in a list

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Im trying to reference complex json object in my model and then display them in a table along with the other object. Below is a an example of the json. How do get to rating and type?

```
   "reviews" : [
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 1,
              "type" : "food"
           },
           {
              "rating" : 3,
              "type" : "decor"
           },
           {
              "rating" : 2,
              "type" : "service"
           }
        ]


Ext.define('FirstApp.model.Details',{
extend:'Ext.data.Model',
config:{
  //  fields:     ['id','recordId','name','icon','vicinity','reference','website','reviews.aspects.type'],


 fields: [ {

name: 'aspects',
mapping: 'reviews.aspects'
},
  {
  name: 'vicinity'
  },
    {
   name: 'name'
  },
  {
  name: 'icon'
  },
 {
  name: 'website'
  }]

  }
  })
```

I am calling the table below but i am getting the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  where the itemTpl is.

```
             {
              xtype:'list',
              store:'Details',
                itemTpl:'<img src="{icon}"></img><h1>{name:ellipsis(25)}</h1>
                <h3>{vicinity:ellipsis(35)}</h3><h2>{website}</2><h2>{reviews}</h2><tpl   for="aspects">
               {rating} - {type}
              </tpl>',
            itemCls:'place-entry'
           }
```

**Note:**

I have tried the following. The errors have stopped and all the other information is displayed but the aspect are still a no show.

```
      itemTpl:new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<div>',
            '<div><img src="{icon}"></img><br>',
            '<h1>{name}</1><br>',
           ' </div>',
           '<div><h3>{vicinity:ellipsis(60)}</h3><h3>{website}</3><br>',
            '<h3>{formatted_phone_number}</h3><br>',
            '<tpl for="aspects"<td>{type}</td></tpl><br>',
           ' </div>',
        '</div>'
        ),
```

And this is now how the model looks:

```
  fields: [
 {

  name: 'reviews'

 },
 {

name: 'aspects',
mapping: 'reviews.aspects'
},

{
name: 'vicinity'
},
{
name: 'name'
 },
 {
name: 'icon'
},
{
name: 'website'
 },
 {
name: 'formatted_phone_number'}]

}
```

**Sample Data:**

```
      "reviews" : [
        {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 3,
              "type" : "food"
           },
           {
              "rating" : 3,
              "type" : "decor"
           },
           {
              "rating" : 3,
              "type" : "service"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Aubrey Skelly",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/101776084849290882399",
        "text" : "Small and wonderful, the food fantastic, service 100% miss this    wonderful restaurant and you will miss a gem in waterford",
        "time" : 1359588944
     },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to map in the model:

```
fields: [
{
    name: 'aspects',
    mapping: 'reviews.aspects'
},
{
    name: 'vicinity'
}
...
```

Then in tpl:

```
<tpl for="aspects">
    {rating} - {type}
</tpl>
```

### Note:

You can not have line breaks in the tpl:

```
//this will throw an error
itemTpl: '<div>this is some content<br>
         this is the same div but I am on a new line now</div>'
```

You have to split the lines:

```
//this is OK
itemTpl: '<div>this is some content<br>',
         'this is the same div but I am on a new line now</div>'
```

Comment: Hi i have tried your solution but i am getting the following error when i declare the table. I have updated the code above to show the where i am getting the error

Comment: You can't have line breaks in the tpl. I added a note to the answer. Please check that.

Comment: Hi I have added in a note in my code. The errors are now gone but the the sub objects are still a no show. I have had a look a json to make sure they are in it and they are.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data?

Comment: Hi i have posted a sample of the json up in my original question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dFqmz/ <- There is an example of working with nested data. This was ripped from http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/platform/templates.html but shows how it works...

Comment: Also, here's an example with your data: http://jsfiddle.net/Ew8DK/ Looks like my answer was wrong: try mapping to just `aspects` instead of `reviews.aspects`